# Unable to open configuration wizard of weblogic server 12.1.1.2.0 after installation. Error :-The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: weblogic12c

In windows env. after succesfull installtion of Weblogic server 12.1.1.2.0.

I tried opening config. wizard for DOMAIN installation and configuration.

I Tried from GUI from Start menu as well as from cmd from C:\oracle\Middleware12c\Oracle_Home\wlserver\common\bin

However getting same error in both cases

Error as "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Java - JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While executing the batch file if "The syntax of the command is incorrect" exception occurs , it means there is a syntactical error in the batch file. On putting echo statements we can narrow down to exactly where there is syntax issue.

Here in my case the issue was the path in system env. variable was incorrect. It had an extra " , because of which below statement threw exception.

if $path == ""